# What is the meaning of page in real estate context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> You know, the thing about real estate accounting is that you can, you
>   can head down the **page** or across the **page**, and everything works out.
>   So, every day, everything adds up.

Is there any separate meaning exist for page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the "page" is an accounting spreadsheet, where you add or subtract numbers ("figures"). "Across the page" likely means that numbers are tallied in columns horizontally, and totals are shown in the final column. "Down the page" likely means that numbers are tallied in rows vertically, and totals are shown in the final row at the bottom of the page. "Everything works out" and "everything adds up" suggests the totals are shown in both directions --in the final column AND the final row of the spreadsheet. The "page" is most likely the document itself (for example, an Excel spreadsheet), and might actually be much larger than one physical page of paper if there are many columns and/or many rows.